# How do I join a fasta file and a txt file?

Tags: join, awk

I have a fasta file that looks something like this:

```
> ASst1|LK||eukaryota|Homo sapiens
YYNRLINTLLDNGIEPIVSIYHWDLPQRLQDLGGWPNIVLAIYTENYARVLFKNFGDRVK
LWITFNEPRIFMGGYTSDTGMAPSINTPGIGDYLTSRTVLIAHANIYHMYEREFKQQQKG
KIGITLTGFWCEPLTPDFTERCERYQQFQLGLYAHPIFTGHGDYPSVVIERVDNNSKVEG
FTTSRLPKLTSEEVNYIKGTYDFFGINFYTAQVGLNGVVGGIPSRERDMGTIVLQDPNWP
> >ASstj1|TH1||eukaryota|Mus musculus 
FWLVVSQLLYFPRDAHCLADIPSEAILDNNIPLINNLTFPDGFLFGAATAAYQIEGAWN
VDGKGPSIWDEFTHTHPEIITDHSTGDDACKSYYKYKEDVQAAKTMGLDSYRFSMSWPRI
MPTGFPDNINQKGIDYYNNLINELVDNGIMPLVTMYHWDLPQNLQTYGGWLNESIVPLYV
SYARVLFENFGDRVKWWLTFNEPQFVSLGYEFRVMAPGIFTNGTGPYIASTNVLKAHA
```

I have another file with information:

```
Homo sapiens    9606    cellular organisms;Eukaryota;Opisthokonta;Metazoa;Eumetazoa;Bilateria;Deuterostomia;Chordata;Craniata;Vertebrata;Gnathostomata;Teleostomi;Euteleostomi;Sarcopterygii;Dipnotetrapodomorpha;Tetrapoda;Amniota;Mammalia;Theria;Eutheria;Boreoeutheria;Euarchontoglires;Primates;Haplorrhini;Simiiformes;Catarrhini;Hominoidea;Hominidae;Homininae;Homo;Homo sapiens 

Mus musculus    10090   cellular organisms;Eukaryota;Opisthokonta;Metazoa;Eumetazoa;Bilateria;Deuterostomia;Chordata;Craniata;Vertebrata;Gnathostomata;Teleostomi;Euteleostomi;Sarcopterygii;Dipnotetrapodomorpha;Tetrapoda;Amniota;Mammalia;Theria;Eutheria;Boreoeutheria;Euarchontoglires;Glires;Rodentia;Myomorpha;Muroidea;Muridae;Murinae;Mus;Mus;Mus musculus
```

I want to jin the two files, such that it looks like the following:

```
> ASst1|LK||eukaryota|Homo sapiens cellular organisms;Eukaryota;Opisthokonta;Metazoa;Eumetazoa;Bilateria;Deuterostomia;Chordata;Craniata;Vertebrata;Gnathostomata;Teleostomi;Euteleostomi;Sarcopterygii;Dipnotetrapodomorpha;Tetrapoda;Amniota;Mammalia;Theria;Eutheria;Boreoeutheria;Euarchontoglires;Primates;Haplorrhini;Simiiformes;Catarrhini;Hominoidea;Hominidae;Homininae;Homo;Homo sapiens
YYNRLINTLLDNGIEPIVSIYHWDLPQRLQDLGGWPNIVLAIYTENYARVLFKNFGDRVK
LWITFNEPRIFMGGYTSDTGMAPSINTPGIGDYLTSRTVLIAHANIYHMYEREFKQQQKG
KIGITLTGFWCEPLTPDFTERCERYQQFQLGLYAHPIFTGHGDYPSVVIERVDNNSKVEG
FTTSRLPKLTSEEVNYIKGTYDFFGINFYTAQVGLNGVVGGIPSRERDMGTIVLQDPNWP
> >ASstj1|TH1||eukaryota|Mus musculus cellular organisms;Eukaryota;Opisthokonta;Metazoa;Eumetazoa;Bilateria;Deuterostomia;Chordata;Craniata;Vertebrata;Gnathostomata;Teleostomi;Euteleostomi;Sarcopterygii;Dipnotetrapodomorpha;Tetrapoda;Amniota;Mammalia;Theria;Eutheria;Boreoeutheria;Euarchontoglires;Glires;Rodentia;Myomorpha;Muroidea;Muridae;Murinae;Mus;Mus;Mus musculus
FWLVVSQLLYFPRDAHCLADIPSEAILDNNIPLINNLTFPDGFLFGAATAAYQIEGAWN
VDGKGPSIWDEFTHTHPEIITDHSTGDDACKSYYKYKEDVQAAKTMGLDSYRFSMSWPRI
MPTGFPDNINQKGIDYYNNLINELVDNGIMPLVTMYHWDLPQNLQTYGGWLNESIVPLYV
SYARVLFENFGDRVKWWLTFNEPQFVSLGYEFRVMAPGIFTNGTGPYIASTNVLKAHA
```

I was thinking, in this example, join would not work. It would work if I first parsed the header into a separate list i.e. grep >, and then joined the two files. But I really need the sequence printed below. Any thoughts would be most helpful.

Comment: What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
awk -F'[\t|]' '
  FNR==NR { dict[$1]=$3; next }
  /^> / { $0 = $0 " " dict[$NF] }
  { print }
' fileLookup fileFasta
```

Assumptions:

- Your lookup file is tab-separated.
- The trailing space after `Mus musculus` in the fasta file sample isn't in the real data file.